# How did the Aurors Apparate directly into the Hogwarts grounds in The Crimes of Grindelwald?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

The Aurors Apparated onto that bridge where Harry Potter would break the Elder Wand decades later in *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald* That's definitely within the Hogwarts grounds.

You could argue that perhaps that was a protection Dumbledore put on the school, but we know that Bathilda Bagshot, the author of *Hogwarts: A History* never covers anything later than the 19th Century, and we also know that Hermione says that she learned of the fact that you can't Apparate or Disapparate within the grounds of the school.

How did they do it then? Did they use a Portkey (or Portkeys, because they arrive separately and not together), like a shirt-pocket pen (because they're not seen holding a tea kettle or a bucket or a boot)? Or was it a mistake that JKR didn't notice when she wrote the film?

Comment: Are the finite physical boundaries of “Hogwarts grounds” opinion-based, or do they have a canon answer (even if that answer might be something like “yes they do exist but have not been precisely detailed yet to answer this”)

Comment: Reopened, this isn't opinion based. An answer may say the protection charms weren't active at the time or that the charms don't extend that far etc. Or even that this is a mistake. But as far as I'm aware it isn't opinion based.

Comment: In the film-canon the no-apparation spell is a lot looser. See Dumbledore apparating in movie 6.

Comment: @Ibid - For apparation lessons and test it is explicitly said the protection at Hogwarts has been lifted (or suspended). It is possible that position of a Head of Hogwarts grants immunity to that protection and/or power to lift/restore it - this is even mentioned in the movie, and in earlier versions of the script it is explicitly shown. See https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Apparition

Comment: @AcePL - I'm referring to the trip to the horcrux cave. In the book they need to walk out of Hogwarts to be able to Apparate. In the film they can do it from within Hogwarts because of headmaster privileges. Hence the movie is a lot less absolute about the no apparation rule.

Comment: @Ibid - ... or less explicit. As I mentioned, the link provided sends to information that in earlier version of the script it is mentioned that Dumbledore explicitly restores the protective charms after he disabled them before the departure. That is a way to be consistent with canon, yet still not be consistent with book. I'd allow that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of universe, there are a couple of reasons I can think of right now:

1. It looked cooler than a bunch of Aurors walking towards Hogwarts from outside the gates.
2. The filmmakers made a mistake.

But I'm not going to make an unfounded assertion without quotes on the subject from the filmmakers.

### In Universe

Earlier in the movie, we see the Ministry placing certain restrictions on Dumbledore.

> TRAVERS
> Will you fight him?
>
> DUMBLEDORE (pained)
> I can’t.
>
> TRAVERS
> Then you have chosen your side.
>
> He flicks his wand once more. **Thick metal cuffs—Admonitors—appear on DUMBLEDORE’S wrists.**
>
> TRAVERS
> **From now on, I shall know every spell you cast. I’m doubling the watch on you, and you will no longer teach Defence Against the Dark Arts.**
> (to THESEUS)
> Where’s Leta? We need to go to Paris!
>
> <sub>*(Fantastic Beasts, The Crimes of Grindelwald: The Original Screenplay)*</sub>

Now, if the Ministry was going to keep an eye on Dumbledore for potential actions that support Grindelwald (as implied), it would make sense for them to have a way to easily and quickly apprehend Dumbledore on such an occasion. They might station some Aurors inside the school, but Dumbledore's, well, *Dumbledore*. The Ministry needed the option to get immediate reinforcements.

The only way to do this was to allow Apparition inside the grounds. Perhaps (off-screen) they ordered Dumbledore to lift the enchantment, but he refused to allow direct Apparition inside the castle. The middle of the bridge would be a good compromise, one that Dumbledore likely agreed to.

---

Of course, it's possible that the middle of the bridge *was* the extent of the enchantment previously. But IIRC, in the eighth movie the defences of the castle extended to beyond the bridge.

Comment: But Dumbledore was not Headmaster at the time. Why would they ask Dumbledore to lift the enchantments?